# CardIO's internal opencv_core conflicts with IDSmart's added OpenCV pod

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, cocoapods, card.io

I've added CardIO and IDSmart frameworks to my iOS project with CocoaPods and for the latter, also OpenCV has to be added as a dependency. The CardIO framework already has opencv_core.a (and opencv_imgproc.a) as static libraries included. The result is, that CardIO and IDSmart don't work together within the same project, because the conflicting OpenCV framework let both of the scanner framework crash within some internal libsystem_c.dylib stuff.

Does anyone have a clue how to isolate the CardIO and IDSmart frameworks or a trick to patch the Podfile, that both frameworks will use the same OpenCV and only once?